# Rhino and Proguard (IllegalArgumentException)

Tags: java, android, rhino

Using rhino library in my Android project and Trying proguard not to obfusticate Rhino jar.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html

JInternalFrame is not part of android package..

proguard setup:

```
    # rhino (javascript)
    -dontwarn org.mozilla.javascript.**
    -dontwarn org.mozilla.classfile.**
    -keep class org.mozilla.classfile.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.* { *; }
    -keep public class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui.Dim$StackFrame { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui.Dim$StackFrame { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui.Dim$StackFrame { public protected *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui.* { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.SwingGui.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.FileWindow.* { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.tools.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.annotations.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.ast.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.commonjs.module.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.commonjs.module.provider.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.debug.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.jdk13.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.jdk15.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.json.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.regexp.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.serialize.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.typedarrays.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.v8dtoa.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.xml.** { *; }
    -keep class org.mozilla.javascript.xmlimpl.** { *; }

    -keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
    -keep class org.apache.commons.codec.** { *; }
    -keep class org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
    -keep class android.net.compatibility.** { *; }
    -keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
    -dontwarn org.apache.http.**

-dontwarn android.webkit.**
```

Exception I get when export unsigned apk in Eclipse:

```
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW] Note: there were 4084 duplicate class definitions.
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW] Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]   Class       = [org/mozilla/javascript/tools/debugger/SwingGui]
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]   Method      = [showStopLine(Lorg/mozilla/javascript/tools/debugger/Dim$StackFrame;)V]
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find any super classes of [org/mozilla/javascript/tools/debugger/FileWindow] (not even immediate super class [javax/swing/JInternalFrame]))
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find any super classes of [org/mozilla/javascript/tools/debugger/FileWindow] (not even immediate super class [javax/swing/JInternalFrame])
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:299)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.evaluation.value.IdentifiedReferenceValue.generalize(IdentifiedReferenceValue.java:65)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:481)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.evaluation.Variables.generalize(Variables.java:136)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.evaluation.TracedVariables.generalize(TracedVariables.java:118)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:682)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:602)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:560)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:264)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:181)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:101)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:79)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:91)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:71)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:504)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:372)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
[2016-01-28 13:02:14 - BRANCH_NOW]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

How to avoid the same?

[SwingGui.java](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/toolsrc/org/mozilla/javascript/tools/debugger/SwingGui.java)
[Dim.java](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/toolsrc/org/mozilla/javascript/tools/debugger/Dim.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JInternalFrame is not part of android package and error clearly says "not even immediate super class".
Also relaised the Rhino SwingGui class was used in desktop java apps, not on android app.
Removed the tools src from Rhino src and applied progaurd to my app..